# How to change shape defaults in keynote?

Tags: keynote, defaults

I'm using Keynote 6.2. Is there a way to change the default properties of shape objects? Specifically, I'd like to get rid of the drop shadow and the advanced color fill. It's a pain to have to change it manually every time I create a new shape.

I figured out that I can create a shape, change the style and go to `Format | Advanced | Create shape style`, then I can delete all the default styles by right clicking, so only my styles show. The problem is that when I create a new presentation, my custom styles disappear and the defaults come back. Is there any way to make them permanent?

Also, can I change the default text size and font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible - you need to exchange the template file within Keynote.

First, save the presentation you want to use as a the new template with a `.kth` extension. Keynote will not directly let you do that, so you need to rename the file in Finder.

Within the `Keynote.app` package, find the folder `Contents / Shared Support / Templates`. To change the defaults of the "White" Theme in standard format, replace `Standard.kth` in the `White` folder.

I have also made a [step by step guide with screenshots](https://gist.github.com/filtercake/e254661a9bdcc9cd4a63#how-to-make-them-go-away-forever) for the method.

Comment: Thanks! If you summarize the steps, I'll mark your response as accepted.

Comment: @nachocab is this as you intended?

Comment: The link is offline.